# spring-session Session implementation not getting CGLIB Enhanced Proxy Bean

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-session, cglib

I'm attempting to drop spring-session into an existing web application that uses session scoped beans. This application is running on Wildfly 10.1.0.Final

When I run the application uses wildfly's internal session management, everything works fine. Attempting to put in a custom implementation of Spring-Session is losing the session bean information. When I debug the application, there is a call for `scopedTarget.userSessionData`, however it is of the underlying class `UserSessionData`, and not the `UserSessionData$$EnhancedBySpringCGLIB$$1234` that has the actual data.

**configuration-spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <bean id="userSessionData" scope="session" class="UserSessionData">
        <aop:scoped-proxy/>
    </bean>
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean class="my.MyHttpSessionConfiguration" />
</beans>
```

This configuration properly creates and registers a `springSessionRepositoryFilter` using `MyHttpSessionConfiguration`. However the problem is when MySession object has a session scoped bean of `UserSessionData`, I get the raw proxied class instance and not the decorated one which has the session values. I was able to verify this by debugging the below SesssionImpl on the #setAttribute method

```
class UserSessionData {
    private String _myValue;

    public void setMyValue(String value) {
        _myValue = value;
    }

    public String getMyValue() {
        return _myValue;
    }
}

final class MySession implements ExpiringSession {
    private final MapSession _delegate;
    private final Map<String, Object> _delta = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean _isNew;

    MySession() {
        this(new MapSession());
        _isNew = true;
        flushImmediateIfNecessary();
    }

    MySession(MapSession session) {
        if (session == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("MapSession cannot be null");
        }
        _isNew = false;
        _delegate = session;
    }

    public boolean isNew() {
        return _isNew;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return _delegate.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public long getCreationTime() {
        return _delegate.getCreationTime();
    }

    @Override
    public long getLastAccessedTime() {
        return _delegate.getLastAccessedTime();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLastAccessedTime(long lastAccessedTime) {
        _delegate.setLastAccessedTime(lastAccessedTime);
        flushImmediateIfNecessary();
    }

    @Override
    public void setMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds(int interval) {
        _delegate.setMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds(interval);
        flushImmediateIfNecessary();
    }

    @Override
    public int getMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds() {
        return _delegate.getMaxInactiveIntervalInSeconds();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isExpired() {
        return _delegate.isExpired();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> T getAttribute(String attributeName) {
        return (T) _delegate.getAttribute(attributeName);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getAttributeNames() {
        return _delegate.getAttributeNames();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAttribute(String attributeName, Object attributeValue) {
        _delegate.setAttribute(attributeName, attributeValue);
        putAndFlush(attributeName, attributeValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAttribute(String attributeName) {
        _delegate.removeAttribute(attributeName);
        putAndFlush(attributeName, null);
    }

    Map<String, Object> getDelta() {
        return _delta;
    }

    private void putAndFlush(String attr, Object value) {
        _delta.put(attr, value);
        flushImmediateIfNecessary();
    }

    private void flushImmediateIfNecessary() {
        if (MySessionRepository.this._flushMode == MyFlushMode.IMMEDIATE) {
            MySessionRepository.this.save(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm missing either a configuration or something because the native WildFly SessionImpl has the correct Enhanced object for serialization when I remove the springSessionRepositoryFilter and let the container handle the session object. Additionally the Spring Controllers have the correct enhanced object. It's just `MySession` that does not appear to be getting it. Any thoughts?

EDIT:
Looks like the core issue is that my spring-security is using a different version of the proxy class when setting members, so I am not getting them in the `MySession` object. Attached are the configurations for Spring-Security

```
public class WebSessionInitializer extends AbstractHttpSessionInitializer {
}


@Configuration
@EnableSpringHttpSession
public class MySessionConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SessionRepository sessionRepository() {
        return new MySessionRepository();
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
        id="imb" 
        version="2.5">

<distributable />

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/configuration-spring.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

The SpringSession filter is correctly added with my implementation. It appears the root problem is when I get into spring-security, it is setting values on a different instance of `UserSessionData` than the one in the `MySession` object. When I use `@Autowired` in MVC Controllers, I get the correct one.

Library Versions:

- Spring: 3.2.14
- Spring Session: 1.3.2
- WildFly 10.1.0.Final

Comment: I would expect that you have the raw object, the actual instance that belongs to your session. The scoped proxy is only a proxy which delegates to the raw object in the session. If you would have the proxy in your session you would never be able to retrieve the actual values.

Comment: So how is spring-session supposed to help distribute sessions? Is there a way I can get the appropriate proxy and externalize it so when my sessions change instances the proxied information goes with it?

Clearly the undertow HttpSession implementation supports this, I'm just trying to figure out how to make this work with the spring-session framework so I'm not tied to specific containers

Comment: Again what you are seeing is the correct behavior. The session contains the plain object, where as what is injected into your object is a proxied instance that delegates the calls to the plain object in the session. You should have the plain object and not the proxied object.

Comment: So there is no way, using spring-session, to have an application use session scoped beans and have it work. Is that the summation we are getting at here because that seems like a serious flaw that should be documented somewhere...

Comment: No it isn't. Your understanding si wrong (and probably I'm writing something you don't understand). The proxy is the scoped object (and there is only 1)  which delegates to the actual instance (the raw object) in the session. So as stated your session MUST have the raw instance and NOT the proxy. That is the way it is supposed to work. The raw instance will get published and used by the other scoped proxies. I strongly suggest a read on how the scoping in Spring works. There is nothing wrong with what you see that is basically the way it is supposed to work and works with distribution as well.

Comment: Okay I think I got the misconception here. In my session I should have an instance of UserSessionData which is the one the Proxied UserSessionData is actually calling methods on correct?

If that is the case it seems my problem is that the UserSessionData object in session is not actually getting values set on it from the proxy calls in my controller?

Comment: Exactly. That is what the proxy does. It looks op the target to use in the scope it handles (request, session, thread etc.) when found it passes on the method call to that instance. So in your session you should have the raw instance and not the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: Is your session actually being used and created? The fact that you have a config and that a filter got created doesn't mean it will be used. You will have to register it with the container as well. Have you tried with the default configuration instead of hacking away at your own implementation of a session?

Comment: Yeah during debugging the HttpSession object is mine, and I can set all the calls. The problem appears to be that the use of UserSessionData in my AuthenticationFilter ( spring-security ) is not getting set correctly. Starting to dive into that with a better understanding of what *should* be happening.

Comment: Is your ordering of filters correct? Your session filter must be the first one.

Comment: I'll double check, but my configuration uses the AbstractHttpSessionInitializer which AFAIK should take care of that for me

Comment: It uses it or extends it? The `WebApplicationInitializer` instances are detected by scanning classes those don't come from an application context. So your `AbstractHttpSessionInitializer` should be passed a configuration class that contains your configuration for spring session. Currently it looks like you are trying to add that configuration class as a regular class but that isn't going to work (or is this xml loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`?)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion:
- I have a `WebSessionInitializer extends AsbtracHttpSessionInitailizer`. The `MySessionConfiguration.class` is a `@Configuration` annotated bean with the `@EnableHttpSession` on it to build all the Spring beans for spring-session, and then the empty constructor for AbstractHttpSessionInitalizer creates the springSessionRepositoryFilter using beans already created in the ContextLoader

Comment: Could you add your initializer, web.xml and content of the `my.MyHttpSessionConfiguration`. I would also suggest to try the default  spring session configuration (is there a reason you need this specialized edition/).

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thank you so much for getting me straightened out. Finally figured out the issue was related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/129 . I was using a RequestContextListener and WildFly was becoming involved in my security filter, so it was in a different session ( Wildfly  ). Switched to the RequestContextFilter and everything is finally working. Thank you again!